# How to draw 2D objects in 3D world

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm attempting to draw particles (which is in 2D) in my 3D world using OpenGL ES 1.1.

The 3D world (without the 2D particles) looks like this:
[3D world without particles](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dujs9bsrcv1l233/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%20Mar%2028,%202013%2010.18.26%20PM.png)

When trying to draw the 2D particles in the 3D world, it looks like this (notice the grid is now moved somehow to the bottom left corner):
[3D world attempted with particles](https://www.dropbox.com/s/erv5vopspa5lt2e/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%20Mar%2028,%202013%2010.17.56%20PM.png)

However, I want it to draw directly over the 3D grid. Any ideas on how to achieve this or why it is moved to the left bottom corner?

Heres my work so far.

```
- (void)drawFrame
{    
    [(EAGLView *)self.view setFramebuffer];

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

/////////////  3D Drawing the Grid floor

    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    static GLfloat z = 0;
    gluLookAt(0, 5, -10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
    z += 0.075f;

    // Rotate the scene
    glRotatef(angle, 0, 1, 0);

    // Draw the Floor
    glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, zFloorVertices);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 42);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, xFloorVertices);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 42);

////////////  2D drawing the particle system

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glOrthof(0.0f, 320.0f, 0.0f, 480.0f, -100.0f, 100.0f);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    [explosion1 update:UPDATE_INTERVAL];

    if (explosion1.active != YES)
    {
        explosion1.sourcePosition = Vector2fMake(200, 200);
        explosion1.active = YES;
        explosion1.duration = 1;
        explosion1.sourcePositionVariance = Vector2fMake(0, rand() % 20);
    }

    [explosion1 renderParticles];

    [(EAGLView *)self.view presentFramebuffer];
}

- (void)initOpenGLES1
{
    // Set the clear color
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0f);

    // Projection Matrix config
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    CGSize layerSize = self.view.layer.frame.size;
    gluPerspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)layerSize.width / (GLfloat)layerSize.height, 0.1f, 750.0f);

    // Modelview Matrix config
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // This next line is not really needed as it is the default for OpenGL ES
    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);

    // Enable depth testing
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, had to reset the gluPerspective of the 3D rendering.

```
// 3D
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

CGSize layerSize = self.view.layer.frame.size;
gluPerspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)layerSize.width / (GLfloat)layerSize.height, 0.1f, 750.0f);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity(); //gets rid of any rotations, movement, or other changes to the virtual world and puts us back at the origin standing upright

....
```